# Install Mosquitto on Ubuntu 18.04 / Chown returns invalid user in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, chown

I am trying to spin up an ubuntu image with the below Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu/de:18.04

ARG  MOSQUITTOVERSION
ENV  MOSQUITTOVERSION 1.5.5

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Install System Utilities

RUN apt-get update     && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y libwrap0-dev libssl-dev python-distutils-extra \
                       libc-ares-dev uuid-dev

# Create Working Directory                 

RUN     mkdir -p /usr/local/src
WORKDIR          /usr/local/src

# Add MQQT Working Directory

RUN     mkdir -p /mqtt/config /mqtt/data /mqtt/log
COPY    config /mqtt/config

# Install MQQT Repository

RUN     wget http://mosquitto.org/files/source/mosquitto-$MOSQUITTOVERSION.tar.gz
RUN     tar xvzf ./mosquitto-$MOSQUITTOVERSION.tar.gz
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/mosquitto-$MOSQUITTOVERSION
RUN     make && make install
RUN     ldconfig 

# Add User ( mosquitto )

RUN     adduser --system --disabled-password --disabled-login mosquitto
USER    mosquitto

RUN     chown -R mosquitto:mosquitto /mqtt
VOLUME  ["/mqtt/config", "/mqtt/data", "/mqtt/log"]

EXPOSE 1883 9001

ADD entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/mosquitto", "-c", "/mqtt/config/mosquitto.conf"]
```

When building using `docker-compose build`, I am getting `invalid Group: »mosquitto: mosquitto`. See some of the output of the build:

```
Step 17/22 : RUN     chown -R mosquitto:mosquitto /mqtt
 ---> Running in 827ca537e624
chown: ungültige Gruppe: »mosquitto:mosquitto“
The command '/bin/sh -c chown -R mosquitto:mosquitto /mqtt' returned a non- 
zero code: 1
```